# How do delocalized π electrons satisfactorily fill π orbitals?

Tags: electrons, valence-bond-theory

[image]

The above example is benzene.

Only six electrons contribute to the 6 π  bonds and pπ  orbitals. Normally, an orbital requires two electrons to satisfactorily "fill" it. I don't understand how this rule is not abided yet bezene is still considered a stable molecule.

Am I to understand that a single electron can be shared by 6 orbitals simultaneously? Do all 6 π orbitals **completely** spread out amongst each other to each this?

Comment: Well, it seems you still don't get resonance and try to get to MO theory... 6 electrons are still in three orbitals which are spread out on molecule.

Comment: @Mithoron Are you saying that each pair of π orbitals form a single orbital? Do you have any good resources to understand resonance?

Comment: That's for MO ^ and about resonance - https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31352/is-the-resonance-depiction-of-benzene-typically-portrayed-incorrectly